# Plotly histogram text parameter not working

Tags: pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I have a plotly histogram where I am trying to add the count on the every bar, `text_auto=True` should work, but it keeps giving a error that `TypeError: histogram() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text_auto'`. I checked in the official docs and it is present in the function.

That's my sample data:

```
    index                                           content
1   api-path-removed-without-deprecation             4236
2   request-parameter-removed                        2024
3   request-property-removed                         622
4   api-removed-without-deprecation                  524
5   new-required-request-parameter                   502
6   new-required-request-property                    422
8   response-success-status-removed                  367
9   request-parameter-became-required                351
10  response-body-type-changed                       229
11  response-property-type-changed                   224
12  response-property-enum-value-added               224
13  response-media-type-removed                      212
14  request-parameter-type-changed                   207
```

This is my code for the graph:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.histogram(top_content_dropped, x="content", y="index", color_discrete_sequence=['#2E86C1'])

fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=1, linecolor='black', mirror=True)
fig.update_yaxes(categoryorder='total ascending',showline=True, linewidth=1, linecolor='black', mirror=True)

fig.update_layout(template='ggplot2',width=1500, height=800)

fig.show()
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong and how could I add the text?

Comment: Check your plotly version, the `text_auto` keyword argument [was added in Plotly 5.5.0](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#550---2021-12-20).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a version issue. `text_auto=True` works fine on my end in:

```
fig = px.histogram(top_content_dropped, x="content", y="index", color_discrete_sequence=['#2E86C1'], text_auto=True)
```

I'm on Plotly version `5.10.0`

#### Plot

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'index': {1: 'api-path-removed-without-deprecation',
  2: 'request-parameter-removed',
  3: 'request-property-removed',
  4: 'api-removed-without-deprecation',
  5: 'new-required-request-parameter',
  6: 'new-required-request-property',
  8: 'response-success-status-removed',
  9: 'request-parameter-became-required',
  10: 'response-body-type-changed',
  11: 'response-property-type-changed',
  12: 'response-property-enum-value-added',
  13: 'response-media-type-removed',
  14: 'request-parameter-type-changed'},
 'content': {1: 4236,
  2: 2024,
  3: 622,
  4: 524,
  5: 502,
  6: 422,
  8: 367,
  9: 351,
  10: 229,
  11: 224,
  12: 224,
  13: 212,
  14: 207}})

top_content_dropped = df

fig = px.histogram(top_content_dropped, x="content", y="index", color_discrete_sequence=['#2E86C1'], text_auto=True)

fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=1, linecolor='black', mirror=True)
fig.update_yaxes(categoryorder='total ascending',showline=True, linewidth=1, linecolor='black', mirror=True)

fig.update_layout(template='ggplot2',width=1500, height=800)

fig.show()
```

Comment: Yes you were right, it was indeed a version issue. Thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: @BrieMerryWeather You're welcome! Glad it worked out for you.